# saveChanges fails if key has a Date field (version 1.2.8)

Tags: breeze

We have an entity with three key fields, one of which is a date  (don't ask - its a summary view with no other obvious key).

Breeze is throwing "*This key is already attached*" error when processing the response from the server after saving changes to the aforementioned entity.

The problem occurs in *MergeEntity* after saving changes. It seems that the initial lookup fails to find the entity on the client, so it tries to add it again resulting in the error.

Near the top of MergeEntity we find the following line...

```
var entityKey = EntityKey._fromRawEntity(node, entityType);
```

...which returns an entityKey._keyInGroup == "1535:::44:::**2013-02-28T11:00:00.000Z**".  Note the third key field which looks like the JSON date string.

Later, when the new entity is (incorrectly) created its entityKey._keyInGroup == "1535:::44:::**Fri Mar 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)**". Now the third field looks like a true javascript date.

The  error finally occurs when we hit this line...

```
attachEntityCore(em, targetEntity, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

...get the "*This key is already attached*" error as the entity we've just saved was obviously already in the client cache all along.

---

**Update: My hacks to Breeze to get this working...**

1) I changed the _*fromRawEntity* function to check for dates and convert them properly so we get the same key values that are produced later for the real entity.  (This code was copied from the *updateEntity* function so should behave identically).

```
ctor._fromRawEntity = function (rawEntity, entityType) {
    var keyValues = entityType.keyProperties.map(function (p) {
        var val = rawEntity[p.nameOnServer];
        if (p.dataType.isDate && val) {
            if (!__isDate(val)) {
                val = DataType.parseDateFromServer(val);
            }
        }
        return val;
    });
    return new EntityKey(entityType, keyValues);
};
```

2) Breeze now found the entity after saving changes but... I then got an error when Breeze tried to update the entities properties using the values returned from the server.  I suspect this is due to an issue in the *defaultPropertyInterceptor* function which was checking to see if the property value had changed...

```
// exit if no change
if (newValue === oldValue) {
    return;
}
```

This will always return false when comparing dates so I hacked this line to be:

```
if (newValue === oldValue || (dataType && dataType.isDate && newValue && oldValue && newValue.valueOf() === oldValue.valueOf())) {
    return;
}
```

From my initial testing everything seems to be working but I'd greatly appreciate any thoughts from folks who are more familiar with breeze :)

**Updated**:  Perhaps the last snippet would be more breeze-ish as...

```
// exit if no change
var comparable = dataType && getComparableFn(dataType);
if (newValue === oldValue || (comparable && comparable(newValue) === comparable(oldValue))) {
    return;
}
```

...although that adds a bit more code considering it is running in every property set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This was fixed in Breeze v1.3.0, available now.

---

Agreed,  this is a bug!  It will be fixed in the next release, out early next week. ( and we now have a test that involves a date as part of a primary key :)

and thanks for finding, analyzing and reporting it. The analysis really helped.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jay, it is greatly appreciated.  Oh and awesome product by the way!